# Scroll view and OnGestureListener

Tags: android, scrollview, onfling

Here is the layout -

```
 <ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout>

    <Layout1>
    </Layout1>

    <Layout2>
    </Layout2>

    <Layout3>
    </Layout3>

    <Layout4>
    </Layout4>

    <Layout5>
    </Layout5>

    <Layout6>
    </Layout6>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have implemented the **onGestureListener** in the **Activity** . 
I have to detect the swipe actions- **swipe up and swipe down** on the individual layouts (*layout 1 to layout 6*). Since the layouts are in a **scrollview** the swipe action(**OnFling**) is not getting detected. 
 How to detect the **onFling** for the child elements of the scrollview ?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Edit : Adding some code -**

Here is the **activity** -

```
  public class ServiceScreen extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener,
    OnTouchListener, OnGestureListener ....
```

The **layout** and the **listener** -

```
RelativeLayout rlCarBrand;
    ....

    rlCarBrand.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Overriden methods -

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
        float arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("LogMessage", "On Fling");
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CustomScrollView class that extends ScrollView.

With this we can change the scrolling enabled property of the Scrollview.

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    boolean bScrollable = false;

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        bScrollable = enabled;
    }

    public boolean isScrollable() {
        return bScrollable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
            if (bScrollable) {
                return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            }

            // only continue to handle the touch event if scrolling enabled
            return bScrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point

        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Don't do anything with intercepted touch events if
        // we are not scrollable
        if (!bScrollable) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for upvoting it. but this community works by giving pointers only. Exact/Specific answer has to be extracted from it only. cheers have a great day.

Comment: Hi...I am used your class CustomScrollView and I want to make the scroll enabled. And I don't know with out scroll enabled, whats the use of scrollView ?? And When I changed bScrollable to true, it dos't work.

Answer (score 1):

try extending ScrollView class and override these onDown and onFling.
something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
    float arg3) {
    super.onFling(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3);   
    return false;
}
```

see if this works.

point is to return false from a scrollview method which is consuming the gesture event.
google it more. i am not sure about it.

Comment: +1. I have implemented what you have suggested . Posted it in the Answer.